# I created a Tag, but can't find it to fill in the definition

Tags: support, tags

I was just granted the Create Tags privilege, so I created one and edited a question to pop it on there. The message says my edit must be peer-reviewed before being accepted. OK. But how can you review my proposed new Tag if I cannot fill in a description? Sure, kill it later if you don't like it, but at least let me get my pitch in.

Comment: These questions will periodically be bumped to the top of the Active list until/unless you accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tag is created when a question is using that tag.

The question you edited isn't using the new nonduality tag because that edit to the question hasn't been approved yet (and therefore the new tag doesn't exist yet).

Are there several other questions which ought to have that new tag?

Also many of the tags we use are Pali. But [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/9595/254) suggests that nonduality is more a feature of Mahayana than Theravada. Is there another, more common, (non-English) word for it than non-duality? The Sanskrit "Advaita" exists but according to Wikipedia it's more Hindu than Buddhist? How much overlap is there between the existing [nagarjuna](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nagarjuna) tag and [non-duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advaita_Vedanta#Relationship_with_Mahayana_Buddhism)?

IMHO we have too many tags at the moment: I say that because half of the existing tags are used for only one or two topics. That's not to say we can't create more... but ...

Comment: Oh, the Irony! One of my questions is tagged Nagarjuna because the Nonduality Tag didn't exist yet, and I was not allowed to invent it. I see Nagarjuna to be a person rather than a practice or method or even a goal. So, I would not think most people would see that tag as the same as Nonduality. Of course, no one created the tag before, so there is no way to know. I am not aware of any better word in English. Advaita is one 'variety' of Nonduality, and there is another major one (Emptiness) and some minor ones, so we need One Tag to Rule Them All, as I see it. I might put it on other questions.

Comment: How many topics would it apply to? If people want to find a topic they can use Search. The real value of a tag is two-fold: to identify topics which don't contain the word e.g. [tag:five-precepts] to tag topics about ethics or alcohol which might not include the word "precept"; and (theoretically) so that users can create a filter (e.g. if hypothetically some user were only interested in 'meditation' or 'reference-request' topics they could set their profile to filter based on those tags).

Comment: Are there a handful (e.g. 5) topics related to nonduality, which could use that tag?

Comment: Well, I started to create an entire SE site about Nonduality on Area51, but I do not know how to gain enough followers for it to go forward. I think that the lack of awareness of it as a path or method (Self Inquiry) or the widespread prevalence of it is hindering people from being able to learn about it. I could talk about it all day. I am writing a book about using nondual practices in daily life, which does not rely on anyone being "enlightened". But is this site where it belongs? Not sure.

Comment: See my relevant Question: http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/9594/what-does-nonduality-correspond-to-in-buddhism

Comment: Do you have any idea how many topics on this site are related to nonduality at the moment: are there as many as, for example, 5 topics already? If not, will there be any new nonduality-related topics soon, which would want to use that tag? It's no big deal, just that (IMO) it's a bit pointless to create tag for just two topics, which is how most of the existing tags have been defined.

Comment: Looking... Philosophy, Modern-World, Mindfulness, Meditation-Insight, Comparative-Religion, Satipatthana, Beginner, Samatha, Daily-Life, Western-Philosophy, Stages-Of-The-Path, Self, Samadhi, Right-Effort, Reality, Insight, Sunyata... If even 5 of those are actually relevant, you have your list. Did I understand rightly?

Comment: @nocomprende Are there 5 questions which could use the tag? One is http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9594/254 ... and you're proposing that http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9431/254 should be tagged nondualism ... http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1585/254 looks like another ... any others?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: when I say "topic" I mean "question", not "tag".

Comment: The 3rd one, yes, but I am reluctant to associate Nonduality strictly with philosophy. It is a daily practice leading to deeper awareness, perhaps like Vipassana? I will try to find more Questions that I would tag.

Comment: nonduality is a subject worthy of a tag, IMO. Pretty important debate in Buddhism (early Buddhism doesn't support the concept, but the argument is a big one).

Comment: @yuttadhammo Thanks for your input. A tag exists if/when it's attached to at least one question. Ahmed, rightly or wrongly, removed it from [this question](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/posts/9431/revisions). Instead I just now added it to [this question](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9594/254), so now [the tag exists](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonduality), its description can be [created/edited](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/525), and it can be attached to other questions as necessary.

Comment: @nocomprende The [tag:nonduality] tag exists now, please see the comment above this one.